# How to redirect from one question to another having same forignkey (quiz name)

Tags: django, django-views, django-url-reverse

I m building quiz app
I have 3 models ( Quiz, Question,Answers)
Question foreign key with Quiz,and Answee foreign key with Questions.
I m successful in showing each question on separate page according to their pk. But to redirect from one question to another until last question

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have to do something like this in your view:

```
def answer(request):
    # here should be code to handle answer

    question = Question.objects.get(pk=request.POST['id'])
    quiz = question.quiz
    later_question = Question.objects.filter(quiz_id=quiz.id, question_id__gt=question.id).first()

    if later_question:
        # redirect to later question
    else:
        # no later question, end the quiz
```